# watin IE instance not reflecting correct values

Tags: c#-4.0, watin

I am testing windows application using watin, I tested this application on Xp(IE8) and windows 7 (IE 9), It is working fine giving me elements present in IE and i can able fill field details.
But same application i tried with Vista IE9 -32bit, it opens IE instance correctly but not able to find the Element collection inside it.

```
ArrayList objDict = new ArrayList();
for (int i = 0; i < ie.Elements.Length; i++)
{
 objDict.Add(ie.Elements[i].Name);
}
```

Please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Watin takes some time to load elements, use thread sleep to allow processing.

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4000);
```

Depending on processors speed u can set sleep time.